# How to programmatically fire an event to click inside an input field without using trigger, change or click events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know, the title sounds insane, but in an attempt to refactor some code, I am having trouble figuring out how to programmatically fire an event without using the following:

1. trigger
2. change
3. click

The code below loads on a hook, and all I need to do is click inside the ID element below, but 'click();' or .on('click') aren't an option.

```
$("#id").data("kendoDropDownList").text(data[i].Text);
$("#id").data("kendoDropDownList").trigger('change'); // code that needs to be refactored
```

Comment: You can’t. But the question is, why such restrictions? Sounds like an XY problem to me.

Comment: @Terry automated tests will not allow it.

Comment: @Terry by the way, I upvoted you because I agree with ya.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use focus function.

```js
$("#id").data("kendoDropDownList").focus()
```